# Can some one explain logical operators in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am doing some practice in chrome console

```
>>var a = 2;
>> a || 3
2 
and
>>a && 3
3
```

Why and how... isn't the output should be true or false, please explain, maybe I am wrong, I think these operator should return true or false.

Comment: Why do you think they should return true or false? Have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Comment: I think because he's used to see them in an "if", which returns true or false

Comment: Be sure you're not confusing the operators with their bitwise counterparts.

Comment: @Nit How would a bitwise operator result in a boolean?

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 For example `!!(1&0)`.

Comment: @Nit You are using the logical NOT operator `!` to coerce the number `0`,resulting from the bitwise operation `&`, to a boolean. The result of the bitwise operator itself is not a boolean. This could be applied to the OP's question too. `!!(2 || 3) //true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical AND (&&) operator evaluates its right operand if `lVal` is a truthy<sup>[2]</sup> 
value.

Analogous, the logical OR (||) operator evaluates its right operand if `lVal` is a falsy<sup>[1]</sup> value.

So, citing the ES5 Specification

> [...] The value produced by a && or || operator is **not necessarily of type Boolean.** The value produced will **always** be the value of **one of the two operand expressions.** <sub>[(ES5 §11.11)](http://es5.github.io/#x11.11)</sub>

From the MDN Article [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

```
Operator            |   Usage               |   Description
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Logical AND (&&)    |   expr1 && expr2      |   Returns expr1 if it can be converted 
                    |                       |   to false; otherwise, returns expr2.   
                    |                       |   Thus, when used with Boolean values,
                    |                       |   && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.
_________________________________________________________________________________________________
Logical OR (||)     |   expr1 || expr2      |   Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns expr2.   
                    |                       |   Thus, when used with Boolean values,
                    |                       |   || returns true if either operand is true; if both are false, returns false.
```

[1] A value is considered falsy if it can be converted to `false`.
  That applies to the values `false`,`0`,`""`,`null`,`undefined`,`NaN`

[2] A truthy value is any value that is not falsy<sup>[1]</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This is no different to what happens if you type a single number into the console, or anything else for that matter. You get back the last thing to be evaluated.

You're effectively saying (in pseudocode, not JS)

```
[return value] = 2 or 3
```

`2` evaluates to `true`, so there's no need to evaluate `3` (short-circuit evaluation). The last thing to be evaluated was `2`, so you get `2`.

```
[return value] = 2 and 3
```

`2` is `true` so evaluate `3` as well. The last thing to be evaluated is `3`, so you get `3`

This is explained well on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking,

> *logical operators return boolean when **all** elements of the equation are boolean type*

Otherwise they work like

```
// b assign a. If !a then assign 3
var b = a || 3;

// b assign a but only if it would evaluate to false. Otherwise assign 3
var b = a && 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have `a || b` JavaScript evaluates the expression and returns the first value which is being evaluated to `true`, in your case `2` (one of the reasons for that is the lazy evaluation).

In the second example `a && b` JavaScript needs to evaluate both - `a` and `b`, in order to make sure the conjunction is `true`. This way JavaScript returns the last thing evaluated to `true` - `3`. If the expression is being evaluated to `false` the interpreter will give you `false` instead (this will happen if any of the operands is being evaluated to `false`).

Answer (score 0):

if you check `a || b` and `a` is converted as a truthy value, this expression will return the first true operand because it's enough to evaluate an `OR` expression, without go ahead in the evaluation (`2 || 3` will return `2`, but `0 || 3` will return `3` since zero is considered as a falsy value)

but if you check `2 && 3` you must be sure that both the operands are true, so javascript will evaluate them all and will return last operand evaluated (if you check `3 && 0 && 2` the expression will return `0` because this operand is false and — as `AND` expression —  there's no need to evaluate further)

This behaviour explains why `||` and `&&` are also called short circuit boolean operators

if you want instead to have the boolean result of the whole expression just try in this way

```
!!(<expression>)
```

Example:

```
!!(2 || 3)      // true
!!(0 || 3)      // true
!!(2 && 0)      // false
```